# newNode is created without returning the created node from createNode(int) function

Tags: c, stack, heap-memory

****Since i have created a function called createNode(int) which is going to return an memory block of type struct node* but i didn't mention return(temp) still code working correctly the operating like insertion, deletion working fine,is there any concept of heap or stack there.?****

```
struct node* createNode(int data){
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    // return temp 
}
void insertNode(int position){
    struct node *temp;
    ....
    temp = createNode(data);
    ....
}
```

Comment: Your compiler will have warned you about not returning a value from `createNode()`. So using it is *undefined behaviour* and some stack data or register just "happened" to align correctly, or contain the pointer which still exists somewhere.

Comment: @WeatherVane just explained it in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an undefined behavior. But I will still try to explain why you were lucky here.

I added a bit more code to the provided one and now it looks like

```
/* test.c */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node {
        int data;
        struct node* next;
};
struct node* createNode(int data){
    struct node *temp;
    temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp->data = data;
    temp->next = NULL;
    // return temp
}
int main(){
    struct node *temp = createNode(12);
    printf("%d %x", temp->data);
}
```

Compile:

```
$ gcc -g test.c
```

Run it with gdb so that you can see disassembly

```
$ gdb -q ./a.out
Reading symbols from /root/a.out...done.
```

Disassemble the function createNode to see where the return value from the `malloc` is placed (Because that's the value we will return back to `main`). Notice that the rax which usually holds the return value of a function contains the return value of malloc (this is where you were lucky)

```
(gdb) disass createNode
Dump of assembler code for function createNode:
   0x0000000000400580 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400581 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000400584 <+4>:     sub    $0x20,%rsp
   0x0000000000400588 <+8>:     mov    %edi,-0x14(%rbp)
   0x000000000040058b <+11>:    mov    $0x10,%edi
   0x0000000000400590 <+16>:    callq  0x400480 <malloc@plt>
   0x0000000000400595 <+21>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)          <== rax register contains the return value of malloc, value is pushed to stack
   0x0000000000400599 <+25>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax          <== rax value retrieved from stack. now rax contains the return value of malloc
   0x000000000040059d <+29>:    mov    -0x14(%rbp),%edx
   0x00000000004005a0 <+32>:    mov    %edx,(%rax)              <== node->next assignment is done here
   0x00000000004005a2 <+34>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax          <== again rax is populated by return value of malloc
   0x00000000004005a6 <+38>:    movq   $0x0,0x8(%rax)           <== node->next is assigned to NULL here.
   0x00000000004005ae <+46>:    leaveq
   0x00000000004005af <+47>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

Disassemble the function `main` to see how the `createNode` was called and from where we are getting the return value. Note that the rax value being read into the temp variable in main's frame.

```
(gdb) disass main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x00000000004005b0 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x00000000004005b1 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000004005b4 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x00000000004005b8 <+8>:     mov    $0xc,%edi
   0x00000000004005bd <+13>:    callq  0x400580 <createNode>     <== createNode called
   0x00000000004005c2 <+18>:    mov    %rax,-0x8(%rbp)           <== rax contains the malloc's return value, so we got the correct value luckily
   0x00000000004005c6 <+22>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005ca <+26>:    mov    (%rax),%eax
   0x00000000004005cc <+28>:    mov    %eax,%esi
   0x00000000004005ce <+30>:    mov    $0x400670,%edi
   0x00000000004005d3 <+35>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005d8 <+40>:    callq  0x400450 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000004005dd <+45>:    leaveq
   0x00000000004005de <+46>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
(gdb) q
```

I hope this explains why we are seeing the correct value in temp, even though there was no return statement in the createNode.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it seems correct and explains the behavior

Comment: i think you explained well brother but the problem is i din't know assembly language.that why i didn't understand the assembly code you have written so please tell me what should i do.

Comment: The assembly you is not written by me. It's disassembly of your compiled code. Take a course/read a book on microcontroller or microprocessor to learn more. Start with 8051 or 8086